# java to have a variable to be modified and used in other classes

Tags: java

I would like to have a variable to be used in all other classes. I can modify that variable in one class and use that new value in other class.

```
class A{
boolean val = false;
}

class B{
val = true;
}

class C{
   if(val){
   //do something
   }
}
```

Comment: Don't do this. You should instead create methods in the `A` class, and then call these to modify the variable. To access the methods, you need to create an object of type `A` using `A a = new A();`.

Comment: See this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983056/how-to-share-a-variable-across-classes-in-java-i-tried-static-didnt-work

Comment: Use static variable @David Sam

Comment: You can declare the variable `static` and access it with `A.val` whenever you need it. This is considering you want to have the same values across classes. Otherwise try @marstran way

Comment: Your question contains invalid code, which means that you have not taken the time to get into Java syntax yet. Please, look at a tutorial, there are some pretty short videos which could help you start with the technology. Without any context you will have a lot of difficulty and frustration.

Comment: Please don't make it static and access it directly! You don't want global state in your program. Look up _encapsulation_.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you can achieve what you want without compromising the need of encapsulation. Create getters and setters in the class having the varaiable, and access that variable in other classes by using those getters and setters.

```
class A{
private boolean val = false; // private modifier needed for encapsulation
public void setVal(boolean val){
    this.val = val
}
public boolean isVal(){
    return val;
}
}

class B{
    //val = true; instead of this, try this------>
    new A().setValue(true); // use setter to set the value.
}

class C{
   if(new A().isVal()){ //use getter here to get the value
   //do something
   }
}
```

The reason behind avoiding using the variable directly inside other classes is that there is always a chance that your variable is modified that can be unsuitable. By using getters and setters you gain full control over the variable, and manipulate it so that any undesirable value doesn't get entered.